# How to log out current user?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, logout, linux-terminal

I'm very very new to the linux world. I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04 and I was wondering how to log out my user using the terminal. I searched the web and all the sites say that I should run the command `logout` or `exit`. But here's the problem. Using `logout` throws me a message saying I should use `exit`. And using `exit` just closes the terminal, I'm still logged in.

How can achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `exit` should be the correct term, when you say "log out" do you mean leave the XWindow (GUI) system?

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. Yes, I mean that or going back where you need to put your user password to log in (just like a log out in Windows).

Comment: In the upper right hand corner there are several small icons. Click on one them at a time, one will present you with the options Shutdown/Logout/restart computer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm asking about doing that from the terminal/command line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using gnome,

```
   gnome-session-quit
```

or

```
  gnome-session-save --force-logout
```

or also

```
  dbus-send --session --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.SessionManager /org/gnome/SessionManager org.gnome.SessionManager.Logout uint32:1
```

If you use KDE,

```
  qdbus org.kde.ksmserver /KSMServer org.kde.KSMServerInterface.logout -1 -1 -1
```

In LXDE,

```
  lxde-logout
```

In XFCE,

```
  xfce4-session-logout
```

Whatever your desktop environment, you can define an alias to make your life easier. Edit the file */home/your_name/.bashrc*,

and place in it, toward the end, the following line:

```
  alias mylg='gnome-session-quit'
```

or whichever command you wish. Source the file,

```
 source .bashrc
```

and you now have a brand new command, *mylg*, which will log you out.

Comment: The first command works on Ubuntu. Thanks a lot!